# String index out of bound exception on following snippet

Tags: java, string, char

I am getting error on this snippet

```
char a[] = new char[5];

Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter values");                

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a[i] = sc.next().charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: How are you entering your values and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're entering a new word each time you're looping? Isn't this nonsense? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am just trying to enter the value inside the array this way. not try to accomplish anything. please don't mind, it is my first question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check input String length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String str = sc.next();
    if (str.length() > i) {
        a[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

But your algorithm is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a[i] = sc.next().charAt(i);
}
```

but what if the user types an string with less than 5 chars??

then you are trying to read an element that is out of the bounds...

that explains pretty clear the reason of the error in your code..

validate the input or even better, make the for loop to go from 0 until the input len.